# Avoid server stuck on SSE (Server Sent Event)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis

My server will get stuck, when users open SSE many times,

Because it seems Redis has some bugs with SSE.

The stream won't be closed even clients close browser or go to another page.

By the way I don't know when where the

```
  logger.info "Stream closed"

  logger.info "Client disconnected"
```

will be invoked ? (it doesn't be invoked when I close the browser)

Is it some workaround to avoid this issue ?

```
  def new_prizes_stream
    # http://ngauthier.com/2013/02/rails-4-sse-notify-listen.html
    begin
      response.headers.delete('Content-Length')
      response.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache'
      response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/event-stream'
      logger.info "New stream starting, connecting to redis"
      redis = Redis.new
      redis.subscribe('messages.create', 'heartbeat') do |on|
        on.message do |event, data|
          if event == 'messages.create'
            response.stream.write "event: #{event}\n"
            response.stream.write "data: #{data}\n\n"
          elsif event == 'heartbeat'
            response.stream.write("event: heartbeat\ndata: heartbeat\n\n")
          end
        end
      end
    rescue IOError
      logger.info "Stream closed"
    rescue ActionController::Live::ClientDisconnected
      logger.info "Client disconnected"
    ensure
      ap "close a live stream"
      redis.quit
      response.stream.close
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is that you do not create a connection on each request/SSE, and benchmark the results. Everytime you execute:

```
redis = Redis.new
```

If you can create the connection (singleton or factory patterns), instead of running this you would instead do something like:

```
redis = myPoolObj.getRedisConnection()
```

You then decide what you want to do on that Pool and how many connections you want to use. I checked the docs at [redis-db](https://github.com/redis/redis-rb) but I did not see a built-in API for this like I saw when inspecting the python one.

You can open an issue on the repo asking if there's a built-in way to execute this without managing your own pool.

Did this help?